# IntelliJ IDEA "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK"

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea

I just installed IntelliJ IDEA and I'm trying to set it up. I've gotten to the part where I need to select my home directory for my JDK.

I tried navigating to my Java installation, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`, and clicked okay but it told me the message above. So, I tried `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7` and that didn't work either.

I tried reinstalling the latest JDK (from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)) and I still couldn't choose my JDK. I even dragged the `.jar` installer I got from the website and the file selector window wouldn't recognize it.

I'm at a standstill and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Because you are choosing `jre` dir. and not `JDK` dir. `JDK` dir. is for instance (depending on update and whether it's 64 bit or 32 bit): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45`
In my case it's 32 bit `JDK 1.7` update 45

Comment: Is that a file, or directory? Because it's not in my Java folder.

Comment: Then you didn't install your `JDK` properly. Check wheter your `JDK` is possibly in: `C:\Program Files\Java` folder

Comment: Its a directory, you should have one for each version of JDK installed.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. It was in Program Files, not Program Files (x86).

Comment: Weird as it states that JDK is bundled: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under `JDK is bundled with all the product installers and it's recommended that you will use the provided JDK version unless there are any specific issues.` `32-bit JDK is located in IDE_HOME\jre directory and is used by the 32-bit product executable.`

Comment: the common mistake is people usually install `jre` instead of `jdk`

Comment: In my case, pointing to the JDK 9 directory did not work, but pointing to JDK 8 did.

Answer (score 32):

For anyone on a Mac with a homebrew-installed openjdk, you need to use the directory under `libexec`: `<openjdk11_directory>/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Thanks to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007751379/comments/360001513560.

Comment: thanks. It's my first time use macOS(M1). 1. make /opt/homebrew visible in Finder
`>open /opt` and then drag homebrew folder to left area in Finder 2. in IDEA choose the right path
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Comment: You saved me a livetime, thanks

Comment: For Linux: `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.2/libexec`

Comment: This is the solution for Mac.
One thing that tripped me up though was setting this in 
Build > Compiler > Scala Compiler > Scala Compiler Server settings
Make sure you set it in Build Tools either sbt or gradle settings if you are running the commands from IDE.

Answer (score 11):

This error occurs because if you choosing the path deep in JDK or JRE.
The exact path that should be chosen is in my case 64 bit

> **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91**

if 32 bit

> **C:\Program Files (86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91**

Comment: For some odd reasons it works only if you install in one of the two paths mention by @Koushal Deva, I believe is a limitation of IntelliJ

Answer (score 4):

May be your jdk is in /usr/lib/jvm/. This variant for linux.

Answer (score 3):

I had `\bin` as part of the path. Up one level of the selected directory worked for me.

Comment: This worked to me. You must put the path without the "bin" folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. But I figured it out by choosing this path:

First at all, you need to select the *C:\* folder. Then, you select *Program Files*. After it, you select *java*, and finally the *jdk* you downloaded. In my case, I downloaded the JDK1.8.0_60 version.

To resume the path:

```
C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

After you are done with it, you can click on the button *next*. Then you select the *create project from templates*. This will create a java application with a main() method. After it, you click next to create the name of you project.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

One thing we should note: the `jdk` should be installed on `C:` drive.

I had JDK installed on my `D:` drive like this:

```
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
```

And it would still give me the same error. For some reason Java should be installed on C: drive.

Comment: Mine is installed on my e:\drive and I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

for me ,with JDK11 and IntelliJ 2016.3 , I kept getting the same message so I decided to uninstall JDK11 and installed JDK8 instead and it immediately worked!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up needing to replace 2017 with 2019, and everything worked fine. /shrug... no other suggestions here worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It got this error because I had managed to clobber jdk1.8.0_60 with the jre!

Answer (score 0):

In case you missed the configuration at the Project Structure(File -> Project Structure), just reconfigure it like below:

For Java
[image]

For Android
[image]

Enjoy coding J

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was to update IntelliJ to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

Although JDK version 8 can be added into IntelliJ IDEA version 2017.2.6, I couldn't add JDK version 11.0.14 into and got the same error. Because of this, I downloaded new version of IntelliJ IDEA version (2021.3.2) and I could add JDK 11.0.14 into IntelliJ easily without any error. Using newer release of IntelliJ than JDK release can be reasonable recommendation for people who meet this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to recent version of intellij work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are in ubuntu, i found the solution to your problem.If you are in mac, i thing is similar.

The thing is that firstly you must install the jdk and jre.

I have it in my /usr/lib/jvm

Then, after that, you must puth the variable $JAVA_HOME in your $PATH in the ~/.bashrc file at the end. But i found that after adding my jre and my jdk, my IDE didn't detect my jdk. So what i do to solve this in my IDE was:

In your command line:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/<your-path>'
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If no problem was detected and all is fine, just do

```
java --version
```

If is detected, next, go to the other step:

=> Open your IDE. In this step, if your IDE doesn't recognize java version or SDK (as in my case), do the following

```
javac --version
```

This is where i solved the problem, becouse it looked like i didn't have javac, so I solved it with:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-<version>-jdk-headless
```

=> Then open your IDE and select the SDK you have just installed. Its like the IDE doesn't recognize de previus jdks.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows, apparently the JDK has to be under **C:\Program Files**.

This does ***not work***:

```
C:\dev\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
```

This ***works***:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
```

(I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.2.4.)

Comment: This is not accurate.