# IntelliJ - The selected directory is not a home for JDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, java-7, intellij-15

Similar to this question [IntelliJ, "The selected directory is not a home for JDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713414/intellij-the-selected-directory-is-not-a-home-for-jdk), I am getting an error that my JDK directory *suddenly* is not valid.

[image: Intellij JDK error]

Even though my JDK directory looks fine to me and worked last time I loaded IntelliJ

[image: My JDK directory]

So I am selecting a valid JDK directory and yet still I get this error.

[image: My Version of IntelliJ]

What could cause this? What could fix this?

Comment: How did you install jdk/java?

Comment: @Rao I downloaded the JDK from oracle's web site.

Comment: Question was how did you install it? Have you just extracted the jdk directory just out of java installer file? or did you install normally following the installer wizard.

Comment: Double click and installed it as admin. I'll try reinstalling it just in case (but tomorrow, I need to wait for a process to finish)

Comment: Can you check if you have `tool.jar`, 'rt.jar' files in JAVA_HOME/lib directory?

Comment: You were right -- somehow the `tool.jar` went missing. I am perplexed. This solved the problem though -- reinstalling JDK 1.7_80. If you submit this as your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because of `tool.jar` and/or `rt.jar` file(s) being missed from `JAVA_HOME/lib` directory.

Reinstalling `java` can resolve this issue.