# “The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK”- jdk-10.0.1

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to set jdk-10.0.1 in my IntelliJ IDEA. the jdk is installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1 and when i pick this path i'm getting the “The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK”.

Comment: What version of IDEA do you have? Versions older than 2017.3 won't work with java 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713414/intellij-idea-the-selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-home-for-jdk)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in ubuntu, i found the solution to this problem. If you are in MAC, is similar.
The thing is that firstly you must install the jre and jdk.

I have it in my /usr/lib/jvm

Then, after that, you must puth the variable $JAVA_HOME in your $PATH in the ~/.bashrc file at the end. But i found that after adding my jre and my jdk, my IDE didn't detect my jdk. So what i do to solve this in my IDE was:

In your command line:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/<your-path>'
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If no problem was detected and all is fine, just do

```
java --version
```

If is detected, next, go to the other step:

=> Open your IDE. In this step, if your IDE doesn't recognize java version or SDK (as in my case), do the following

```
javac --version
```

This is where i solved the problem, becouse it looked like i didn't have javac, so I solved it with:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-<version>-jdk-headless
```

=> Then open your IDE and select the SDK you have just installed. Its like the IDE doesn't recognize de previus jdks.