# Why I can't set my jdk path in idea intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-10

Please refer to the picture below.

I changed the default java installation path to `D:\Program Files\Java\`

I created a new java project.
Firstly, it reminds me the java path is not existed and the program cannot run.
When I tried to modify the path to my location, it rejected me saying it's an invalid path.
Why?
Please note: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713414/intellij-idea-the-selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-home-for-jdk) post didn't resolve my question:
I know the difference of jdk and jre; I do reinstalled latest java repeatedly.

Only, I didn't want to install java to C disk. I have set my JDK_HOME and JRE_HOME to my location.

You're right! IntelliJ version 2018 resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> **2017.1 is not compatible with java 10**. For official java 10 support please use 2018.1. Also It is possible to use jdk10 with 2017.3 build,
>   but there would be no syntax highlighting.

[Source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000366370-Cannot-setup-project-sdk-as-JDK10-), emphasis mine

Answer (score 1):

Java 10 support starts from build **2018.1**.

take a look at this [IDEA 2017.1.1 doesn't detect JDK 10](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000125230-IDEA-2017-1-1-doesn-t-detect-JDK-10)

You have to upgrade your IDE now.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because your IDE is out of date. Updating your IDE [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) should do the trick.